# Decimal, Float, Double or Varchar to store Price Amount in database?

Tags: database, decimal, varchar

My question is What is the best solution to store Price value in database, keep in mind that I'm going to retrieve entries from that table by this field descending. Decimal, float, double or regular varchar ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't ever use varchar to store monetary data. Use `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC` type for this.

`DECIMAL/NUMERIC:` Exact precision, operations slight slow. Use this type in data that needs exact number precision. E.g.: Monetary, factors, etc.

`FLOAT/DOUBLE:` Inexact precision, operations might be faster than `DECIMAL/NUMERIC`. Use this type in data that inexact operations is acceptable. E.g.: Age, scores, etc.

`VARCHAR:` Alphanumeric data. E.g.: Name, description, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Decimal is exact precision. It will be your best bet.